# Django admin doesnot reflect dynmaic choices in choiceField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have 2 projects running on 2 different systems.(call them A and B)

in A I have a model which has one dynamic choice field.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
      field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=get_field1_list())
      #..some more fields
```

and in `get_field1_list()` function I call an API which is running on system B and it returns a list of tuples(required in choice field) which is coming from ModelB (Project B)

```
[(a,A), (b,B), (c,C)...]
```

Now when I make changes in this model(ModelB) from admin panel(lets say added one more row) so I was expecting that it should reflect in the modelA choices.
I refreshed the admin panel but still it doen't show. but when I restart server A(local server), I can see newly added(in system B) row in ModelA(System A) choices.

So My question is why this happening?  how can I resolve this issue as in production I might not want to restart uwsgi or nginx everytime.

Comment: `choices` are not dynamic in this case. It is what `get_field1_list` returned on first call. Wouldn't it better to set relation between `ModelA` and `ModelB` with `ModelA.field1 = ForeignKey(ModelB)`?

Comment: they both are separate projects..I can't import and directly use foreignkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.9, I'm doing this way

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

class ModelA(models.Model):

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    # ..

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._meta.get_field('field1').choices = lazy(get_field1_list, list)()
```

NOTE that i'm using `lazy`. you can ignore that